# Report for time tracking

Tags: reporting, history-tracking

Reports for time tracking
I need a get report on following

1) How long does it take each case owner to resolve a single case?
2) How long does it take each case owner on average to resolve a case?

I need to get similar kind of metrics and need to generate a report.. Can anyone suggest how could we achieve it?